# Add a background image to a react navigation drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

I'm trying to add a background image to a react navigation drawer

```
import React from "react";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { StackNavigator } from "../../routes/HomeStack";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { DemonHunterIcon, DruidIcon} from "../../icons";

import { DemonHunter } from "../../screens/DemonHunter";
import { Druid } from "../../screens/Druid";

import { HomeHeader } from "../../components/Header";
import { ImageBackground } from "react-native";

const { Navigator, Screen } = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function Drawer() {
  return (
    <ImageBackground source={require("../../assets/drawer-bg.png")} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Navigator initialRouteName="Home" hideStatusBar>
        <Screen
          name="Home"
          options={{
            drawerIcon: () => <MaterialIcons name="home" size={24} color="black" />,
          }}
        >
          {() => <StackNavigator component={Home} name="Home" header={HomeHeader} />}
        </Screen>
        <Screen
          name="Hunter"
          options={{
            drawerIcon: () => <HunterIcon />,
          }}
        >
          {() => <StackNavigator component={Hunter} name="Hunter" />}
        </Screen>
        <Screen name="Demon Hunter" options={{ drawerIcon: () => <DemonHunterIcon /> }}>
          {() => <StackNavigator component={DemonHunter} name="Demon Hunter" />}
        </Screen>
        <Screen name="Druid" options={{ drawerIcon: () => <DruidIcon /> }}>
          {() => <StackNavigator component={Druid} name="Druid" />}
        </Screen>

      </Navigator>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

Tried wrapping the drawer on  tag but didn't work. Any clue on how to do this? I have searched a lot and didn't found a solution.

Also if you can tell me how to change the font family and color of the labels I'll be thankful :)

Comment: Create a custom drawer element! You can resolve all the above-mentioned issues.

Comment: Sure, I'll look into that, would it be with the drawerContent prop?

Comment: yes, drawer content prop